# How do number of partitions and iterations work in Spark Word2Vec?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, word2vec

I'm currently training an embedding on a large dataset using Spark Word2Vec, implemented on Python.

In the inputs for the model there are `numPartitions` and `numItertions`. Up until now I have been training on 1 partition and 1 iteration. The dataset is 3TB of text data. So this is taking a long time. How should I determine the number of partitions and iterations?

How do number of partitions in PySpark ML work?

Comment: It would depend on how big of a cluster you have. Number of partitions in a way tell how much parallelism you can have in your application. Of course you need comparable number of cores as well in order to process multiple partitions in parallel. If you have only one core then each partition will get executed sequentially.

Comment: I have 1.5TB of ram and 160 cores. @Amit.

Comment: If you configure 160 partitions then in an ideal case each partition could be 3TB/160 ~ 18GB. I am not sure how your data looks like but just wanted to show how you can divide and try to use as many cores as possible at once.